# Can't Get Coordinates From MKMapView Using UILongTouchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using iOS 6, and I've read dozens of ways to accomplish  this (including many from stack overflow) without success.

Here's what I've tried, separated into "stages":

1. Create a `UILongTouchGestureRecognizer` to receive long touches for the `MKMapView`.

   - I've tried adding a `UILongTouchGestureRecognizer` via my Storyboard, and hooking up the outlets, delegates, etc. through the Connections Inspector.
   - I've tried creating the `UILongTouchGestureRecognizer` programmatically, initializing it using `mapView` as target, `self` as target, and `self.view` as target.
2. Receive the touch gesture using the selector method from the `UILongTouchGestureRecognizer`, get the `CGPoint`, and convert it to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` object.

   - I've tried:

     - Using [mapView convertPoint:(CGPoint) toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
     - Using `MKMapPoint aPoint = MKMapPointMake(aCGPoint.x, aCGPoint.y);` first, and then using               `MKCoordinateForMapPoint(aMapPoint)` to get the `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.
     - Both Directly accessing the UILongPressGestureRecognizer and using the `(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender` from the method call to get the x,y for the CGRect.
3. Results

   - In a nutshell here is what I've been getting when checking the values using `NSLog`, irregardless of the methods used.
          - For the X,Y given from the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, x seems to fluctuate to somewhere in the range of 200, and 420. Y ranges from ~400 - 700.
          - The latitudes and longitudes triggered by a long touch & printed to the log, strangely, only vary in the 3rd - 6th decimal values after the decimal point of 85.051XX (latitude) and  -179.9997XX (longitude).

Here's examples of some of the code I've tried

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSLog(@"View did load");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:mapView action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
}

- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CGPoint point: x - %f y - %f", point.x, point.y);
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    NSLog(@"Coords from \"locCoord\": lat - %f lng - %f", locCoord.latitude, locCoord.lon);

    MKPointAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

   [addAnnotation setCoordinate:
   [self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
}
```

Hope someone can help me, because I'm completely stumped on this one.

Just to reiterate, the end goal is to get a coordinate of where the user "long pressed
 a mapView", and then (something else I can't get to work) drop a pin at that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking back at an old project of mine that works in iOS 6 we seem to have almost identical code (same source tutorial I guess). The difference being that I am checking the `state` and that my mapView variable is not being reset in the viewDidLoad. You seem to be allocating a new one after the gesture recogniser and you haven't shown any code for adding it to your viewController. I'd guess that you've managed to separate the one on screen from the one in code. If your MKMapview is meant to be on screen through the life of the viewcontroller, let IB manage the allocation and assignment.

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
        [self addPinAtLocation:locCoord];       
    }

}
```

Comment: Mind posting the rest of the code? Now I'm just getting 0.000000 for latitude and longitude. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: There is no other code. I attached the gesture recogniser in IB.

Comment: What do you get when you use this code after you create your coord?: `NSLog(@"Lat: %f Lng: %f", locCoord.latitude, locCoord.longitude);` Also, could you verify how your connections are set up in IB? I've got my UILongPressGestureRecognizer set up like this: Delegate->mapView Sent Actions:handleLongPress: Referencing Outlets: gestureRecognizers->mapView. Is yours the same?

Comment: Stupid mistake on my part. Used `@property MKMapView *mapView` and didn't connect my mapView from IB using an IBOutlet. Once I did that, everything worked fine. ...the simplest answer is usually the best one.